# how to initialize existing index in elasticsearch 6 using RestHighLevelClinet

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

i have an index in elasticsearch which is already created and i want to make use of RestHighLevelClient to initialize the index but not creating new index.

how do i achieve the same and don't intend to use transport client.

Someone please explain in java how to initialize and query on the existing Index.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to initialize a RestHighLevelClient:

```
RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
    RestClient.builder(
            new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
            new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")));
```

Then you need to use IndexRequest to index a document:

```
IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest(
    "posts", 
    "doc",  
    "1");   

String jsonString = "{" +
    "\"user\":\"kimchy\"," +
    "\"postDate\":\"2013-01-30\"," +
    "\"message\":\"trying out Elasticsearch\"" +
    "}";

request.source(jsonString, XContentType.JSON); 
IndexResponse indexResponse = client.index(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Here we indexed a docuemt of type "doc" in index "posts" with "id" equal to 1.